# Xna Fullscreen fails

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I can't run an simple XNA window in fullscreen when I have hooked up my 2 monitors
The code I use to get it to fullscreen is:

```
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        graphics.PreferMultiSampling = false;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

It works when I disable my second monitor in windows, but is their a way to fix the issue (code wise)

Comment: I have never experienced this issue, and I have 2 monitors. Could it be with PreferMultiSampling? Maybe the problem is somewhere else in your code, or maybe it is in your system settings.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you mean by "fails"? Does it throw an exception? (Details?) Does it simply not go full screen? Does it cause your monitor to launch itself off your desk?

Comment: I starts minimizing and maxiziming , sometimes it opens corectly sometimes it doesn't , the PreferMultiSampling  doesn't change anything

Comment: Have you tried graphics.ToggleFullScreen() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried applying the changes on the resolution before setting it to fullscreen?